# WebImage Resize is this behavior correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

So, i upload big image (2000x3000) and want to resize it, then crop and ok.

As u can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWwpg.png

I have WebImage with 3000 height, 2000 width. So, resize please to 402x602, then crop back to 400x600.

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB5KX.png

**But what the hell?**

Why i really get 401x602?!

p.s. Don't have enought reputation to insert images directly in post, sry for that.

Comment: Please post the code you are using.

Comment: What code u really need? image.Resize is in Assembly System.Web.Helpers.dll, v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the numbers, with out the +2 pixel you have a perfect ration of the changing of the image size  because `3000/600 == 2000/400 -> 5 ratio`

But if change it with the +2 pixel you change that ratio on the width/height as

```
3000/602->4.98, 2000/402 ->4.97,
```

that are two different numbers, and then image code that try to keep the ratio of the image, is eat 1 pixel.

The correct way is to add the 2 pixels after the resize, or actually add the same amount of pixel base on the ratio.

Comment: @user1612334 No is not strange - you add the same amount of pixel in two numbers, and you thing that this made them the same, but you must add them according to the ratio of the image :) - if you see 2000/401 -> 4.98 that is what you get, the same as 3000/602 !